# Creating a backup-maker program in C# windows form

Tags: c#, windows, backup, windows-forms-designer, backup-strategies

I'd like to do a program which can make copies of a folder/subfolders to a specific destination in every hour. I've made a simple program which can copy files if I press a button, but its not scheduled and it forgets the source and the destination every time I open it. Could you please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide your code in the description? `forgets the source and the destination` Did you define some variables to save them? Or you set them via somthing like `TextBox`? You want the program keeps the path you input when reopen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Console case**

```
static public void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Starting background process, press ESCAPE to stop.");
  var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(ProcessFiles, null, 1000, 2000);
  while ( Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape ) ;
}

static private void ProcessFiles(object state)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Copy files... " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
}
```

You can also create a service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-windows-services-in-c-sharp/

*Output*

[image]

**WinForms case**

Add a `Timer` from the *Component* tab of the Visual Studio Toolbox and set the desired `Interval` property in milliseconds hence 3600000 for an hour.

Double click on it to create associated the event method:

```
private void TimerCopyFile_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LabelInfo.Text("Copy files... " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
}
```

You need to start it somewhere or set the enabled property.

```
timer.Start();
```

Thus you can design your app as you want to offer for example settings and you can use a TrayIcon.

**WPF case**

In addition to the `System.Threading.Timer` there is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer

**ASP.NET case**

In addition to the `System.Threading.Timer` there is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.timer